# servicestack user auth can't authorize

Tags: xamarin.ios, servicestack, servicestack-auth

```
 Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
                    () => new AuthUserSession(),
                    new IAuthProvider[] { new BasicAuthProvider(new AppSettings()), }));

            Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());

            container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
            var userRepository = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
            container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRepository);

            string hash;
            string salt;

            new SaltedHash().GetHashAndSaltString("password", out hash, out salt);
            userRepository.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth
            {
                Id = 1,
                DisplayName = "JoeUser",
                Email = "joe@user.com",
                UserName = "hal",
                FirstName = "Joe",
                LastName = "User",
                PasswordHash = hash,
                Salt = salt,
                Roles = new List<string> { RoleNames.Admin },
                //Permissions = new List<string>{"GetStatus"}
            }, "password");
```

this is global asax file and  i auth with this code

```
 [Route("/ClientList/", "POST")]
    [ Authenticate]

    public class ClientGet
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }

    }
```

in monotouch stage when i try to

```
client = new JsonServiceClient ("http://sampleurl.com/api/authenticate/Basic?format=json") {
                UserName = "hal",
                Password = "password"
            };
```

or
  client = new JsonServiceClient ("http://sampleurl.com/api) {Username="Hal", Password="password");

it gives me request time out problem

is there any update?

thanks

Comment: You say the request times out, rather than ServiceStack returning an error. Can you access the metadata of the service in the browser by going to `http://sampleurl.com/api/metadata` have you correctly set your service url and port i.e. in place of `sampleurl.com` `http://<server-address>:<server-port>/api`?

Comment: i already tried all of this, with rest console i can reach data but when i use [auth] system can't find it..i have tried lots of combination 
   var clientX = new JsonServiceClient ("http://212.175.132.168/api/Auth/Basic") {
    UserName = "hal",
    Password = "password"
   };
   ////   var clientX = new JsonServiceClient ("http://212.175.132.168/api/authenticate/Basic?format=json") {

Comment: client = new JsonServiceClient ("http://212.175.132.168/api") { UserName = "hal", Password = "password" };
  
   girisX.TouchUpInside += delegate {
    // var response = client.Post (new  ClientGet { username = userN.Text, password = passN.Text });
    client.UserName = "hal";
    client.Password = "password";

    var response = client.Post (new  ClientGet { username = "Memed", password = "1234" });